# Flask-Login: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, attributeerror

I am using python3 with Flask 1.1.1 and Werkzeug 0.16.0. 
I am trying to use the Flask login manager to manage the user sessions. 
For the DB am running sqlite3.
Below is the class definition

```
class UserData(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self._authenticated = False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self._authenticated

    def is_active(self):
            return True
        # return true if user is activte and authenticated

    def is_annonymous(self):
        return False
        # return true if annon, actual user return false

    def get_id(self):
        global connection
        user_id = get_user_id(self.username, connection)
        unicode_user_id = load_user(user_id)
        if unicode_user_id != 0:
            self._authenticated = True

        print("userid:" , unicode_user_id)
        return unicode_user_id
```

In the function get_id , I fetch the user-id from the DB and set the self._authenticated flag for the authentication.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return int(user_id)
```

The below is the protected page which should be accessed only but authorized users.

```
@app.route('/device_detail', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def device_detail_operation():
    error = None
    return render_template('device_detail.html', error=error)
```

After the user login when I try to access the protected page directly am running into attribute error. 
Below is a stack trace

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2019 22:52:26] "GET /device_detail HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 259, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 348, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'
```

Answer (score 1):

In load_user function, you need to return user object. I did not use sqlite but i guess that have something like that: `user = models.User.query().filter(models.User.email == user_id).get()`

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = models.User.query().filter(models.User.email == user_id).get()
    return user
```